# Cannot boot into ubuntuDDE after install vs2019

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, grub

I have installed ubuntuDDE dual boot with window 10, but yesterday after I switch to window in order to install visual studio 2019 I can't boot back to my UbuntuDDE anymore. it didnt show the Grub manager like before and straightforward log into window so i check my disk partition in Window 10, and ...[it become like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDsgj.png)

as you can see, the free space of my Ubuntu partition is 100% and i cant access to these partition :(.

but when i use usb-boot to log into UbuntuDDE "try version" and open Gparted, it show my data still there, not free 100% diskspace like window 10 does.
idk if it's all deleted and i have to re-install and lose all my data or is there anyway to solve this issue. Please help :"(

Comment: problem solved, i did try boot-repair on ubuntu, and then it works, all my data still there